# Is a placeholder return type allowed for main?

Tags: c++, c++14, return-type-deduction

Is the following valid in C++14?

```
auto main()
{
    // ...
}
```

Will the return type deduce to `int` even though we don't need to use an explicit `return 0;`?

Comment: That's not a "practical problem you actually face", or is it?

Comment: @DanielFischer Who cares? It's an interesting (useless) edge case.

Comment: I don't know if this was special-cased in the rules, but if it wasn't, expect `void`.

Comment: Why? `auto` is one letter longer than `int`.

Comment: @Dave I don't. I'm just curious why the question arose.

Comment: The compiler writer would have to write a special rule for that. Why would they do so?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan they had to write a special rule for implicit `return 0;` anyway.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I bet that the standards makers would not write that now if they could start over

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I bet they would, since it's a fairly recent addition (I believe).  But I bet if they considered this point, they would simply forbid use of `auto` as the return type of `main()`.

Comment: I removed your C++14 tag. [This meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177625/c14-or-c1y) came to a concensus to wait until the Final Draft Standard is released before using it instead of C++1y.

Comment: How about just `auto { ... }`. Obviously, I want a startup function here; automatically deduce the declaration! :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, it isn't allowed. Paragraph 7.1.6.4/10 of the C++14 Standard Draft N3690 specifies:

> If a function with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type has no `return` statements, the return
> type is deduced as though from a `return` statement with no operand at the closing brace of the function
> body. [...]

This means that omitting a `return` statement in `main()` would make its type `void`.

The special rule introduced by paragraph 3.6.1/5 about flowing off the end of `main()` specifies:

> [...] If control reaches the end
> of `main` without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing
>
> ```
> return 0;
> ```

The wording says that the "effect" during the *execution* of the program is the same as though a `return 0` was present, not that a `return` statement will be added to the program (which would affect type deduction according to the quoted paragraph).

**EDIT:**

There is a [Defect Report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1669) for this ([courtesy of Johannes Schaub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134975/will-automatic-return-type-deduction-work-for-main/17135093?noredirect=1#comment37231162_17135093)):

> Proposed resolution (November, 2013):
>
> Change 3.6.1 [basic.start.main] paragraph 2 as follows:
>
> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. It shall have a **declared** return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined. <s>All implementations</s> **An implementation** shall allow both
>
> - a function of `()` returning `int` and
> - a function of (`int`, pointer to pointer to `char`) returning `int`
>
> as the type...

Comment: But is deducing the return type as `int` an "effect of executing `return 0;`"?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Well, the effect is not that of "adding a `return 0`", and 7.1.6.4/10 specifies "If a function with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type has no return statements [...]". Flowing off the end of `main` does not add a `return` statement, so the rest of the sentence should apply, and the return type should be deduced to be `void`

Comment: Are you saying that the "the effect of executing" means that no compile time effects happen? Does such a conceptual distinction actually exist? I habe a hard time believing that.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I'm saying the compiler would arrange things behind the hood so that the execution would be identical to the one that would be obtained if a `return 0;` statement were explicitly present in the program.

Comment: Ah i see. I guess it can be read that way. But nontheless, an issue report was posted about this by some clang developer to clarify the spec here.

Comment: @Andy: So you're saying that a conforming compiler can reject the code as ill-formed, but if it continues with compilation, the runtime behavior must be the same as if the `return 0;` statement were explicitly present, at least down to the presence or absence of undefined behavior?

Comment: @Ben: Not sure I understand. I'm saying the compiler should reject the code as ill-formed, because the absence of an explicit `return` statement would make type deduction infer that `main` has return type `void`, which is illegal

Comment: @Andy: But is a diagnostic required for `void main()` or is it merely undefined behavior?

Comment: @Ben: 3.6.1/2 does not specify that "no diagnostic is required", so the compiler should emit a diagnostic

Comment: Per discussion on the core reflector, this will not be allowed even if `main` contains a *return-statement* returning `int`. `main` is in effect a redeclaration of an entity in the runtime, and its **declared** return type must match that entity.

Comment: So what's the effect of `return 0;` in a function that returns `void`?

Comment: @immibis: Not sure I understand the point of your question, anyway returning *anything* from a function whose return type is `void` is incorrect and will cause a compiler error.