# How to resolve const/non-const conflict in template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, type-deduction

I have a function template that takes a `std::pair` as well as a value of one of the pair's types.  I'd like to call this function using an entry from a `std::map` as the pair argument.

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void do_stuff(std::pair<T1, T2> const &pair, T1 const &val) {
  // Imagine that this does something important...
}

int main() {
  std::map<int, float> foo { { 0, 0.0 } };

  do_stuff(*foo.begin(), 0);
}
```

This fails to compile because the type of the map's entry is `std::pair<const int, float>`, so the type deduction for `T1` has conflicting types: `const int` via the `pair` argument, and `int` via the `val` argument.

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:12:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘do_stuff(std::pair<const int, float>&, int)’
   do_stuff(*foo.begin(), 0);
                           ^
test.cc:5:6: note: candidate: template<class T1, class T2> void do_stuff(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const T1&)
 void do_stuff(std::pair<T1, T2> const &pair, T1 const &val) {
      ^~~~~~~~
test.cc:5:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cc:12:27: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter ‘const T1’ (‘const int’ and ‘int’)
   do_stuff(*foo.begin(), 0);
                           ^
```

What's the best way to resolve this conflict?  Ideally I'd like `T1` to be deduced as `int`, but it's OK for it to be `const int` if that's more straightforward to implement.

I've found that I can resolve the error by using either `std::remove_const` or `std::decay` on the type of the `val` parameter:

```
void do_stuff(std::pair<T1, T2> const &pair, typename std::remove_const<T1>::type const &val) {
```

but I don't know which of those is more appropriate, or if there's some other solution that'd be better.

Comment: not sure to understand... why don't you define `do_stuff()` accordingly; I mean `template <typename T1, typename T2>
void do_stuff(std::pair<T1 const, T2> const &pair, T1 const &val)` ?

Comment: @max66, I want it to also work with pairs whose first type *isn't* const.  (Since the whole parameter is passed by const reference, constness of the pair's members is irrelevant; either const or non-const should be allowed for either of them.)

Comment: Have you tried to make construction in the map? I mean  `std::map< const int, float > foo { { 0, 0.0 } };`

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to use `std::add_const` instead of using the keyword `const` directly.

The roundtrip via a template prevents type deduction via this parameter type:

```
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template< class T1, class T2 >
void do_stuff( std::pair<T1, T2> const& pair, std::add_const_t<T1>& val )
{
    // Imagine that this does something important...
    (void) pair; (void) val;
}

auto main()
    -> int
{
    std::map<int, float> foo { { 0, 0.0f } };
    do_stuff(*foo.begin(), 0);
}
```

Comment: "`auto main() -> int`" You took this too far

Comment: @Dani do you mean the `int` is one newline too far apart from the function name in his code?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf So is `auto main` allowed in C++17 now? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134975/will-automatic-return-type-deduction-work-for-main)

Comment: @kfsone: That's a strange question. The syntax was introduced in C++11. Automatic type deduction is something else.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class T>struct identity{using type=T;};
template<class T>using no_deduce=typename identity<T>::type;
```

Wrap the second type in `no_deduce` to block deduction.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void do_stuff(std::pair<T1, T2> const &pair, no_deduce<T1> const &val) {
  // Imagine that this does something important...
}
```

This both works and is clear why you are doing it.

Now, it might be worth considering what you want to do if `T1` is a reference type, and what `const&` does in that case.  Imagine `T1` is `int&` then `int& const&` becomes just an `int&`.

This may not be what you want.

Maybe what you want, what you really really want, is:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void do_stuff(std::pair<T1, T2> const &pair, std::remove_reference_t<T1> const &val) {
  // Imagine that this does something important...
}
```

If you want a `const&` you gotta forget your `&`, if you wanna prevent `val` from being modified you better make sure it is `const`.  Now, don't go wasting your precious `const&`, `remove_reference_t` and it'll be just fine.

If you wanna deal with `volatile`, you gotta get with `remove_volatile_t`.  Tie them together forever in a `template<class T>using clean_t=std::remove_cv_t<remove_reference_t<T>>`.  If you wanna `const&` you have got to

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void do_stuff(std::pair<T1, T2> const &pair, clean_t<T1> const &val) {
  // Imagine that this does something important...
}
```

Simply `const&` is to easy, but that's the way it is.

Answer (score 2):

Not really elegant but I suppose you could separate `T1` in two different template paramenters.

Something like

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void do_stuff(std::pair<T1, T2> const &pair, T3 const &val) {
  // Imagine that this does something important...
}
```

You can add a check, via `std::enable_if_t`, to impose a correlation between `T1` and `T3`; by example

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::remove_const_t<T1>, std::remove_const_t<T3>>::value>>
void do_stuff(std::pair<T1, T2> const &pair, T3 const & val) {
  // Imagine that this does something important...
}
```

Comment: That resolves the compile error, but also allows the caller to pass a completely different, unrelated type.  (It'll still produce a compile error if `T3` is incompatible with `T1`, but the error will come from somewhere within the function's implementation, where it's less likely to be clear what the actual problem is.)

Comment: @Wyzard - you can impose, via SFINAE, that `T1` and `T3` are (`const` more or less) equal; uglier than before but... Modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: In `typename = typename std::enable_if_t` the second `typename` is not needed, that's the point of the `_t` alias.

Comment: @Oktalist - you're right; thanks; I'm used to C++11 and `std::enable_if<>::type`.